# How to remove substring in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to takeout any value which is before `(Impressions)`.
Ex if i have value `YouTube TrueView for Reach (Impressions)`, I will need `YouTube TrueView for Reach`.

Another example is `YouTube Bumper (Impressions)` --> `YouTube Bumper`

I am currently using :

```
validated_df=validated_df.withColumn("MediaNm", when(col("MediaNm").like("%Impressions%"),F.regexp_extract(F.col("MediaNm"), r".*?\(", 0)).otherwise(validated_df.MediaNm))
```

I am getting blank as a result of this.

Comment: Can you provide sample data input?

Comment: media_name->column
YouTube TrueView for Reach (Impressions)->value
YouTube Bumper (Impressions)->value

Expected value that needed to be extract from above values are 
YouTube TrueView for Reach
YouTube Bumper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to remove the string `' (Impressions)'`: for this, you just need a `regexp_replace`

```
validated_df.withColumn('MediaNm', F.regexp_replace('MediaNm', ' \(Impressions\)', ''))

+--------------------------+
|MediaNm                   |
+--------------------------+
|YouTube TrueView for Reach|
|YouTube Bumper            |
+--------------------------+
```